# Inno Setup: Stop trying to close application

Tags: inno-setup

Inno Setup offers to close applications that might be interfering with the installation.
Is there a way to exclude an application by name?

There is one specific application that should NOT be closed.
When I run the setup as VERYSILENT, I can not untick this application being closed.

Thank you.

Comment: What's your script? Is the application that can't close yours or a third party application?  As far as I know there isn't a way to limit it based on the application name unless the install has been written to handle that situation.

Comment: The reason that these applications are listed is that they are holding open files that need to be replaced.  As a result if they're not closed they will cause the installation to either fail or to require a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no use to just disable the closing of **one** application. If that application hold a lock on one of your files (who needs updating) it will still require a restart. So why not just disable the whole CloseApplications functionality and let it restart if needed. It **won't** restart if it is not needed. (The only downside i see is it wants to restart if that one application is not running but another, who holds a lock on one of your files, is)

You can disable it by setting the following in `[setup]`:

```
CloseApplications=no
```

or using `/NOCLOSEAPPLICATIONS` as startup parameter.